# how does clock and calendar icon works

Tags: iphone, ios, icons

I am curious to know how does `Clock` and `Calendar` icon on `iOS` shows the real time and date respectively? Can I make such Icons for my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Calendar` shows the date, but `Clock` only shows the time starting in iOS7.

You can't do those things in your own app, that's an Apple thing. Maybe in the future Apple will provide an API for this, but not right now.